# Does Objective-J support protocols like Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, protocols, cappuccino, objective-j

I can't seem to find any documentation on the Objective-J language itself. Does it support `@protocol` like Objective-C?

Is there a language spec somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

[Source](http://groups.google.com/group/objectivej/browse_thread/thread/90e757ae808e6dd0/c5c850a7e8bac247?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=protocol#c5c850a7e8bac247)

Answer (score 0):

yes, with this patch: [Protocol support for Objective-J](https://github.com/cappuccino/cappuccino/pull/1974)